# Filter data on blank cell

Tags: javascript, full-text-search, slickgrid

I am looking for a way to filter out empty cell data from my grid, I have implemented sorting, I am able to get all the blank cell at one place, but it would be great if any kind of filtering is possible on blank cells.

What I was thinking (theoretical), that if we could map the empty cell with some kind of expression e.g. {blank}{`}, anything of that sort then maybe the filtration is possible. But have no idea how to implement that.

Comment: Have you looked into using dataView's filter funcitons? See [this example](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html)

Comment: Normal filtering is working absolutely fine, the requirement is to filter on blank cells, I tried assigning {--} to cells that are not defined, now blank cell are coming on typing `{ ` but when deleting this from search the entire table is not coming back, it's stuck with the rows having blank cells only.

Comment: What does "blank" look like in your data model? (i.e. the property on your rows)? You might need use a filter like `typeof row.prop != 'undefined' && row.prop != null` or similar.

Comment: @Edward Thanks for the suggestion, I know it's a little wired kind of question to ask to filter on blank cells. 
Blank in my data model is an empty cell in the table.

Comment: The filter doesn't care what it looks like (how the formatter renders 'blank'), what the filter looks at is the data property it has access to in the filter method. I've actually done this a couple of times, so I'm wondering what I'm missing in your setup. Can you [edit] and add an example of a row and the `filter` method?

Answer (score 0):

```
function filter(item) {
                for (var columnId in columnFilters) {
                    if (columnId !== undefined && columnFilters[columnId] !== "") {
                        var c = grid.getColumns()[grid.getColumnIndex(columnId)];
                        if (item[c.field] !== undefined)
                        {
                            if (item[c.field].toString().toLowerCase().search(columnFilters[columnId].toLowerCase()) === -1) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        } else if(columnFilters[columnId] === "#blank")
                        {
                            return true;
                        } else 
                            return false;

                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
```

adding this line "else if(columnFilters[columnId] === "@"){return c;}"
got me all the blank cells (that do not have any data), cell property = "undefined". By typing '@' in the search box all the blank cells get filtered.